# How to make comma and semi-colon direction-insensitive of the latest f,F,t,T command

Tags: cursor-movement

I can customize the <kbd>n</kbd> and <kbd>N</kbd> keys to always search backward and forward respectively irrespective of what the last search direction was with the following commands:

```
nnoremap <expr> n (v:searchforward ? 'n' : 'N')
nnoremap <expr> N (v:searchforward ? 'N' : 'n')
```

I want to achieve similar effects for the <kbd>,</kbd> and <kbd>;</kbd> keys, i.e. I want <kbd>,</kbd> to always jump backward and <kbd>;</kbd> to always jump forward. But I can't find any similar variable in `:h eval.txt` for this purpose. Maybe I'm missing some thing.

> How do I make <kbd>,</kbd> and <kbd>;</kbd> unaware of the direction of the latest `f`,`F` or `t`,`T` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
nnoremap <expr> ; getcharsearch().forward ? ';':','
nnoremap <expr> , getcharsearch().forward ? ',':';'
```

check `:h getcharsearch()`

Comment: The whole thing *was* in fact in `:h eval.txt`. Don't know why I missed it.